# vite/vue3, import.meta.glob broken after node upgrade

Tags: vue.js, vite, tsconfig

In my code I have

```
const all = import.meta.glob('@/components/*.vue')
```

which has been working fine, until I had to upgrade from node 16 to node 20.  Now when I try to 'npm run dev' I get

```
Failed to resolve import "../../../../../../../c:/development/" etc
```

It would seem something broke with resolving paths.  Making some weird absolute/relative hybrid.
I've been trying a bunch of different things, but can't seem to get it to work again.

My vite.config.ts has the

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
  }
}
```

I would assume it's something to do with this area? maybe? except, if I try

```
const all = import.meta.glob('/src/components/*.vue')
```

it still has the same result

Comment: i would recommend to upgrade vite/vue to the latest version. maybe there's some problem with using older vite/vue with a newer node. also try to delete `node_modules` and `npm i` again